# How to get 2 json objects at once?

Tags: android, json, post, android-volley

I'm using volley to get json object, I'm getting data like this

{"resultUser":19}
{"resultUser2":13}

How to get either the second one (resultuser2) or both?

```
try {
    JSONObject o = new JSONObject(response);
    String data = (String) o.get("resultUser2");
    if (!data.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "user2 id" + data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //UserDetailsActivty.this.finish();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ohh! Sorry,,Signing Up Failed ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: `{"resultUser":19} {"resultUser2":13}` is not a valid JSON. Put them into an array or redesign the scheme.

Comment: It Makes scenes

Comment: if you can not get your data as valid json. you can try to split with "}" and some string operations to make your data a valid json. But I think you should find a way to fix your data at where it comes from

Comment: yeah , I've thought of this idea

Comment: So the web service should return an only single value or array ?

Comment: Hey bro, U can validate your json  from website http://jsonviewer.stack.hu

Comment: yes.. I'm Just Considering if validation is not possible

Answer (score 0):

you can use JsonArray to iterate through all the jsonobjects like this

```
try {

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

for (int i =0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.get(i);
//do whatever you want to do with the data
}
} catch(Exception e) {

}
```

Comment: it gives me this error "foreach not applicable to type JSONArray"